# Terraform-use same tf file for multiple deployment?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, automation, terraform

```
resource "aws_instance" "win-example" {
  ami = "${lookup(var.WIN_AMIS, var.AWS_REGION)}"
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
 count="${var.count}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_id}"]
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name}"
  user_data = <<EOF
<powershell>
net user ${var.username} '${var.password}' /add /y
net localgroup administrators ${var.username} /add

winrm quickconfig -q
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}'
winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5985" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5986" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5986 action=allow

net stop winrm
sc.exe config winrm start=auto
net start winrm
</powershell>
EOF

  provisioner "file" {
    source = "test.txt"
    destination = "C:/test.txt"
  }
  connection {
    type = "winrm"
    timeout = "10m"
    user = "${var.username}"
    password = "${var.password}"
  }

tags {
Name="${format("${var.username}-%01d",count.index+1)}"
}

}
```

If i run code above more than once-specifying other value for var.username, instance got recreated, is it possible to use same tf file multiple times, to create new machines with different user name ?

Answer (score 0):

[Count](https://www.terraform.io/intro/examples/count.html)

With an array with different usernames and passwords that correspond to it.

Dont't put that secrets.tfvars in scm though,

> We don't recommend saving usernames and password to version control,
>   But you can create a local secret variables file and use -var-file to
>   load it.
>
> You can use multiple -var-file arguments in a single command, with
>   some checked in to version control and others not checked in. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> $ terraform apply \
>   -var-file="secret.tfvars" \
> ```

in secrets.tfvars

```
instance_count = 3
usernames = ["jeff","jason","jake"]
passwords = ["jeff_password","jason_password","jake_password"]
```

Then in the resource

```
resource "aws_instance" "win-example" {
  ami = "${lookup(var.WIN_AMIS, var.AWS_REGION)}"
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
 count="${var.count}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group_id}"]
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name}"
  user_data = <<EOF
<powershell>
net user ${var.usernames[count.index]} '${var.passwords[count.index]}' /add /y
net localgroup administrators ${var.usernames[count.index]} /add

winrm quickconfig -q
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}'
winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5985" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5986" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5986 action=allow

net stop winrm
sc.exe config winrm start=auto
net start winrm
</powershell>
EOF

  provisioner "file" {
    source = "test.txt"
    destination = "C:/test.txt"
  }
  connection {
    type = "winrm"
    timeout = "10m"
    user = "${var.usernames[count.index]}"
    password = "${var.passwords[count.index]}"
  }

tags {
Name="${format("${var.username}-%01d",count.index+1)}"
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

turned out i had to create subfolder for each user (./terraform/user1,./terraform/user2....), copy all tf files to these folders,create new security group for every user and only that machines stopped recreating, for every user new machine has been created without destroying it for previous one

```
#!/bin/python
import json
import os.path
import shutil
from os import mkdir
from pprint import pprint
from python_terraform import *


json_data=open('./my.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

json_data.close()



def myfunc():

  tf = Terraform(working_dir=final_path, variables={'count':count,'INSTANCE_USERNAME':user})
  tf.plan(no_color=IsFlagged, refresh=True, capture_output=False)
  approve = {"auto-approve": True}
  print(tf.init(reconfigure=True))
  print(tf.plan())
  print(tf.apply(**approve))
  return







for i in range (0, len (data['customers'])):
    #print data['customers'][i]['email']
    k=data['customers'][i]['email']
    #print(k.split('@')[0])
    user=k.split('@')[0]
    #print(user)
    count=data['customers'][i]['instances']
    #print(count)
    #enter = int(input('Enter number of instances: '))
    start_path="/home/ja/terraform-course/demo-2b/"
    final_path=os.path.join(start_path,user)
    if not os.path.exists(final_path):
       os.makedirs(final_path)
    shutil.copy2('./vars.tf', final_path)
    shutil.copy2('./sg.tf', final_path)
    shutil.copy2('./windows.tf', final_path)
    shutil.copy2('./provider.tf', final_path)
    shutil.copy2('./test.txt', final_path)
    final=os.path.join(final_path,'sg.tf')
    final1=os.path.join(final_path,'windows.tf')
    with open(final, 'r') as file :
      filedata = file.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace('allow-all', user)
    with open(final, 'w') as file:
      file.write(filedata)
    with open(final1, 'r') as file :
      filedata = file.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace('allow-all', user)
    with open(final1, 'w') as file:
      file.write(filedata)
    myfunc()
```